# Can I use a certificate created for nginx for my own server on the same machine?

Tags: ssl, nginx, certificate

Nginx is set on a machine where my server is located. Nginx has already generated an SSL certificate for the domain we are using. Can I use this same certificate to set up SSL for my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it depends, but probably.

To begin, it is not advisable to re-use a certificate on multiple web-servers. This multiplies the risk associated with the certificate use. I won't get into the details of why, cryptography is a big subject.

In short, if the Subject or Subject Alternative Name (SAN) of the certificate matches the DNS name of your web server, you can probably use the certificate again. In truth, even if the Subject/SAN do not match, the certificate would "work" but anyone accessing the page would receive an error indicating as such.

It sounds like you have two web servers running on the same machine so one URL would be https://nginxserver and the other would be https://otherserver (where otherserver is a DNS entry for a different IP on the same machine) or https://nginxserver:someportotherthan443. The extra port on the URL won't affect the certificate use but it does make accessing the page more complicated for the user. If it's a different DNS entry, the certificate would need to have that listed in the SAN field.